# Kotlin smart cast fails but only with operator function

Tags: kotlin

The following is an example of this problem. Why am I unable to invoke supplier using the operator function? If I make supplier non-nullable `Supplier<Int>` I have no search problem

```
operator fun <T> Supplier<T>.invoke(): T = this.get()

val supplier: Supplier<Int>? = (Supplier<Int> { 5 })

if (supplier != null) {
    // Fails: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Supplier<Int>?
    supplier() 
    supplier.invoke() // fine, smart casts
    supplier.get() // fine, smart casts
}
```

Comment: The above code runs fine for me. What fails for you?

Comment: @mattfreake as I commented, the invokation of `supplier()` fails with the following error message. Maybe I'll try switching my kotlin compiler version? It's 1.3.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed for me in a later of version of IntelliJ + Kotlin plugin